# How to use a hindi character sequence in php file?

Tags: php

I want to use the following code in my php file and would want to use hindi font in doing that -

```
var $font = 'aparaj.TTF'; 

  function generateCode($characters) { 
    $possible = '23456789ABCDEFGHJKLMNPQRSTUVWXYZ'; 
    $possible = $possible.$possible.'2345678923456789'; 
    $code = ''; 
    $i = 0; 
    while ($i < $characters) {  
      $code .= substr($possible, mt_rand(0, strlen($possible)-1), 1); 
      $i++; 
    } 
    return $code; 
  }
```

Instead of using the character sequence '2345623456789ABCDEFGHJKLMNPQRSTUVWXYZ' I want to use hindi characters.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what have you tried? did you write some code that related to hindi characters?

Comment: I am not understanding how to write the code in hindi in the first place

Comment: Do you understand how this code works?

Comment: Yes I do, this will generate a random sequence of characters from the given set>

Comment: Ok, so now you need to add the hindi chars there

Comment: Yes,  how do I add this while writing the code?

Comment: Are you asking "how to open the text editor and write hindi text" ?

Comment: Yes and also make sure the code works

Comment: Do you have hindi keyboard? If yes - just enter the text. I'm sorry but I don't understand the problem. Is the problem with your code or with your computer?

Comment: My problem is with the fact that if I enter the text using a virtual hindi keyboard will the code accept the text and work?

Comment: Try and let us know...

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about Hindi, but if you plan to use multi-byte character, then make sure you use `mb_substr` and `mb_strlen`.

Code below seems to work

```
function generateCode($characters) { 
    $possible = 'औऐआईईऊभङघधझढञओअइफखशभख'; 
    $possible = $possible.$possible.'औऐआईईऊभङघधझढञओअइफखशभख'; 
    $code = ''; 
    $i = 0; 
    while ($i < $characters) {  
        $code .= mb_substr($possible, mt_rand(0, mb_strlen($possible)-1), 1); 
        $i++; 
    } 
    return $code; 
}
```

Fiddle: http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/c35a-23p8

Comment: Thanks, can you also explain how you managed to write devanagari in the that font?

Comment: I copied and paste from Wikipedia. I have no Hindi keyboard.
If you want to write Hindi and has no Hindi keyboard, you can use virtual keyboard here. http://gate2home.com/Hindi-Keyboard

Comment: Thanks, but I want to know that if I replace the character sequence with hindi characters will the code work?

Comment: @AnandSaran As I said in the answer, you should also change `strlen` to `mb_strlen` and `substr` to `mb_substr` because Hindi characters are multi-byte character.